# Connection reset by Alert in Mirth

Tags: mirth

I am trying to set up an alert for a channel to send emails. The problem is that when a channel produces an alert, on having tried to send e-mail the mistake takes place: "Connection reset". The server of mail is external to the company.

To prove the sending of message in Mirth, I have defined a channel that when it receives a hl7 message sends a mail to a certain direction with the following code javascript:

```
var smtpConn = SMTPConnectionFactory.createSMTPConnection();
smtpConn.send('example1@mailserver.es', '', 'example2@mailserver.es', 'subject', 'body');
logger.info('mensaje enviado');
```

Producing the same mistake:

```
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1925)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1684)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)
```

The Setting configuration is:

SMTP Host: ipsmtphostserver, Port: 465,SendTimeOut:2000,DefaultFromAccess:anyemail@mail.com, SecureConnection:I have tried with both TTL and SSL,RequiereAuthentication: Yes.

I have thought that the problem was firewall or antivirus, but I have deactivated a moment them and it follows the problem.

Comment: Connection reset can mean, that there is no server on the hostname and port you use. Are you sure, that you use the right server settings, e.g. have you tried with other applications with the same settings?

Comment: I have configured Mozilla Thunderbird in the server where I have installed Mirth: Input: IMAP, port 993,  Output: SMTP, port 465 SSL/TLS. With this configuration  I was able to send mail with Thunderbird, but in Mirth I am not capable of sending mail with the configuration of salient mail. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: It might help to have a look with tcpdump or wireshark to see what really goes on, especially compared to the thunderbird installation. It might also be, that Mirth speaks the wrong protocol (e.g. tries a starttls on port 465 instead of immediatly starting with ssl) and thus the mail server just resets the connection (usually not the case, e.g. they close but don't reset).